# salesforce report

Tags: visualforce, reporting

i have created a simple report on account and contact. and calling this report  using reporting api like:--

```
<apex:page >

<analytics:reportChart reportId="00O28000002jhwW"/>

</apex:page>
```

This visualforce page is called as  a home page wide component.
first time when home/home.jsp is loads its look good.But when i am changing the grouping criteria it show error.

> The report chart is not available because the running user doesn't
>   have access to a field used for grouping or aggregation.

how ever my user profile is system administrator and given permission to all object view All. and  on field too.

**Update**

i have changed the report created a report for case field and given all permission on  FLS.The screen shot is atteched.even than the issue is same.

[image: Field level security screen]

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Please check for FLS of the Object though you are system Admin.  It might happen by mistakenly you left that field.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.i given all permission to all field.even than the issue is same.is there any another work around?.i am working on developer account.is there any issue with that? or it is reporting api issue?

Comment: I just found alink related to above query. Hope it helps you in some way out.
REFER: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000212310&language=en_US